# How to execute the string returned from Format function PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to run this sql string (the sql command which will be return from the format function) in PostgreSQL

```
execute format('CREATE USER %I PASSWORD %L', 'test1', 'test1');
```

but received the error:

```
ERROR:  prepared statement "format" does not exist
SQL state: 26000
```

How can I execute the returned SQL?

Comment: You are trying to do it as plain SQL, which means of course that you can't - it is trying to execute a prepared statement instead. The "EXECUTE" is a pl/pgsql command. All this is quite thoroughly covered in the online manuals and I recommend spending half an hour at least familiarising yourself with how they are laid out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('CREATE USER %I PASSWORD %L', 'test1', 'test1');
END;
$$
```